# PyNoAppError: The wx.App object must be created first! [Python 3.7]

Tags: wxpython

I spent several time to figure out this problem. I am testing example that I take from https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/blob/master/samples/ribbon/ribbonbar_demo.py. When I run this code, I get the following error message:

```
  File "C:/Workspace/gui/RibbonDemo.py", line 86, in __init__
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, pos, size, style)

PyNoAppError: The wx.App object must be created first!
```

How can I figure out this problem. I use Spider et Python 3.7 on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

See the sample at this link:

https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.lib.agw.ribbon.html

For any wxPython application, you need to create a wx.App object first. The wxPython demo is a bit special as it does create it for you under the hood.